# D3 charts - Data overlapping issue with huge data

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I have generated a bar chart using D3 charts. Here is the js code

```
function renderChart(filename) {


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



var data = [
  {"name": "india", "population": 120},
  {"name": "uk", "population": 200},
  {"name": "us", "population": 300},
  {"name": "china", "population": 50}
];
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.population); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.population); });
}
```

Here is the link to fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/scfx9/

Here, the width of the bars increases and decreases according to the size of the data. When ever I pass huge data the bars shrink and data gets overlapped as the div size is fixed. How do I make the size of the bars constant and allow the users to use the arrow keys to move the data as in the example below

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the example you posted, he is handling the `keydown` event for arrow keys:

```
d3.select(window).on("keydown", function() {
    switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
      case 37: year = Math.max(year0, year - 10); break;
      case 39: year = Math.min(year1, year + 10); break;
    }
    update();
});
```

Your data will need to work a little bit differently but the concept of windowing is the same.  Each time the arrow key is pressed your handler will produce a `data` array that represents the current window into the overall data.  Then you will bind the array to enter new bars and exit old ones and you can decide the kind of transition you want.

One difference in your case compared with the example is that his example uses a fixed scale on his X axis, so he never needs to change the axis.  In your case because you're using an ordinal scale and your values will be different for each data window, you'll need to update the domain on your X scale and redraw the axis (possible in a transition if you like).

Comment: I tried modifying my code according to that example but failed, I would be grateful if you could modify that fiddle any time.

Comment: That's not a minor modification. You need to think through the example again from the perspective described above. If you have specific questions along the way, SO can help. But not to write the whole thing for you. :)

Comment: OK, I took a crack at it for you.  The chart will only ever show 2 bars (just as an example) and each time you use the arrow key right or left it will push one bar out and introduce the next one. The transitions aren't perfect but it should be enough to get you started.  Note that because the fiddle has a bunch of windows, you need to click on the chart window before using the arrow keys.  I've commented out `window.focus` because that broke the editor in the fiddle. You can add it back once the chart has its own page.  http://jsfiddle.net/6BwC7/6/